# Summary Statistics for Multiple Factors in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have gameplay data that looks like this for each game:

| Id | Pos | Team | Opp | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Duck | Frog | 2 |
| 1 | B | Duck | Frog | 15 |
| 2 | B | Duck | Frog | 20 |
| 3 | C | Duck | Frog | 7 |
| 4 | C | Duck | Frog | 9.5 |
| 5 | C | Duck | Frog | 10 |
| 6 | A | Frog | Duck | 3 |
| 7 | A | Frog | Duck | 0.5 |
| 8 | B | Frog | Duck | 17 |
| 9 | B | Frog | Duck | 13 |
| 10 | B | Frog | Duck | 21 |
| 11 | C | Frog | Duck | 8.5 |

I would like to obtain the average score for each position and team (as well as for their opponent) so the result looks something like this.

| Id | Pos | Team | Opp | Score | Team_A_Avg | Opp_A_Avg | Team_B_Avg | Opp_B_Avg | Team_C_Avg | Opp_C_Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | Duck | Frog | 2 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 1 | B | Duck | Frog | 15 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 2 | B | Duck | Frog | 20 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 3 | C | Duck | Frog | 7 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 4 | C | Duck | Frog | 9.5 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 5 | C | Duck | Frog | 10 | 2 | 1.75 | 17.5 | 17 | 8.8333 | 8.5 |
| 6 | A | Frog | Duck | 3 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |
| 7 | A | Frog | Duck | 0.5 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |
| 8 | B | Frog | Duck | 17 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |
| 9 | B | Frog | Duck | 13 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |
| 10 | B | Frog | Duck | 21 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |
| 11 | C | Frog | Duck | 8.5 | 1.75 | 2 | 17 | 17.5 | 8.5 | 8.8333 |

What is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output; why is `Team_A_Avg = 2` even for rows where `Pos = B` and `Pos = C`?

Comment: @mbenoo Please could you review the suggested answers and accept +/- upvote if one has answered you question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented by @Maurits Evers, it doesn't really make sense the way you have presented your output. It seems like you want a separate output, with the mean score for each team and position. Also, you've only given us one score for each row, which I presume is the score for the `Team`, so we haven't got the opponent's score to calculate that average. I would use `dplyr` `summarise` function.

Here's your data:

```
game = data.frame(id = c(0:11),
                  Pos = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C","A","A", "B", "B", "B","C"),
                  Team = c("Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck","Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog"),
                  Opp = c("Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog","Frog","Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck","Duck"),
                  Score = c(2, 15, 20, 7, 9.5, 10, 3, 0.5, 17, 13, 21, 8.5))
```

First the average by position:

```
library(dplyr)
Pos_av = game%>%    #creat a new data.frame called "Pos_av" which is taking data from "game" and piping it (%>%) into different functions 
  group_by(Pos)%>%    #first into a grouping function so we chose the variable we want to find the average for
  summarise(Pos_Mean = mean(Score))    # the we pipe into summarise function where we name our new variable (Pos_Mean) and then define the function we want to use to summarise it (in this case the mean)
```

which gives us :
[image]

and then the same for the team means:

```
Team_av = game%>%
  group_by(Team)%>%
  summarise(Team_Mean = mean(Score))
```

[image]

To get the average for each team and position, group by both variables:

```
Both_av = game%>%
  group_by(Team, Pos)%>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Score))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by looping through the dataframe and all conditions to set the value for each cell, depending on the mean value for this condition and this opponent/team:

```
## The name of the variable holding the data.frame is "df"

## Expand the dataframe to contain your desired variables
for(t in c("Team","Opp")){
  for(p in c("A","B","C")){
    df[[paste(t,"_",p,"_","Avg",sep="")]]=NA
  }
}

## Loop through the data to compute the means
for(i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  for(t in c("Team","Opp")){
    for(p in c("A","B","C")){
      ## For each case i, each Team t, and each Position p, compute the mean and store it:
      df[[paste(t,"_",p,"_","Avg",sep="")]][i] = mean(df$Score[df$Team==df[[t]][i] & df$Pos==p])
    }
  }
}
```

This results in the dataframe:

```
> df
   Id Pos Team  Opp Score Team_A_Avg Team_B_Avg Team_C_Avg Opp_A_Avg Opp_B_Avg Opp_C_Avg
1   0   A Duck Frog   2.0       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
2   1   B Duck Frog  15.0       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
3   2   B Duck Frog  20.0       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
4   3   C Duck Frog   7.0       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
5   4   C Duck Frog   9.5       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
6   5   C Duck Frog  10.0       2.00       17.5   8.833333      1.75      17.0  8.500000
7   6   A Frog Duck   3.0       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
8   7   A Frog Duck   0.5       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
9   8   B Frog Duck  17.0       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
10  9   B Frog Duck  13.0       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
11 10   B Frog Duck  21.0       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
12 11   C Frog Duck   8.5       1.75       17.0   8.500000      2.00      17.5  8.833333
```